# Why can't I put an output in an excel file?

Tags: python, tkinter, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create a code that writes the inputs to an excel file with xlsxwriter but the output in the xlsx file is this:

```
<function Act_Key at 0x7fbf27008670>
```

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time
import os
import sys
import pathlib
from pathlib import *
import xlsxwriter

#command
def succes():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/home/matteo/Scrivania/Healir/Healir/Healir_PY/bin/files/info.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Nome')
    worksheet.write('B1', 'Act.Key')
    worksheet.write('A2', str(Nome))
    worksheet.write('B2', str(Act_Key))
    workbook.close()
    config.destroy()
    os.system('python3 /home/matteo/Scrivania/Healir/Healir/Healir_PY/bin/project/menu.py')

#var
def Nome():
    global value1
    value1 = e1.get()

def Act_Key():
    global value2
    value2 = e2.get()


#gui
config = Tk()
config.title('Healir')
config.configure(bg='#7b4397')
config.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

#input

tk.Label(config, text="Nome").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(config, text="Codice Seriale").grid(row=1)
e1 = tk.Entry(config)
e2 = tk.Entry(config)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

suc = Button(config, text='Okay', command=succes)
suc.place(x=300, y = 15)

config.mainloop()
```

The xlsx file is created correctly and the words in A1 and B1 are written correctly. The problem is only with the inputs from the Tkinter Entries.

Comment: Change `str(Nome)` to `e1.get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
    worksheet.write('A2', str(Nome))
    worksheet.write('B2', str(Act_Key))
```

`Nome` and `Act_Key` are functions. Getting the `str(..)` value will just print their function IDs:

```
>>> def foo():
...   print("abc")
... 
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x102951200>
>>> str(foo)
'<function foo at 0x102951200>'
```

...which is what you're currently printing to the .xlsx file.

You need to **call** those functions: `Nome()` and `Act_Key()`.

```
    worksheet.write('A2', str(Nome()))
    worksheet.write('B2', str(Act_Key()))
```

Then, in those functions, simply return the `Entry` text:

```
def Nome():
    return e1.get()

def Act_Key():
    return e2.get()
```